# method must have a return type pointing to NewCall Handler class in my code. What am i missing

Tags: c#, methods, return-type

In the class i am defining a method called NewCallHandler. Even though i am calling this function inside another method, but it gives me error: **method must have return type**.

```
class CallHandler
{

      public NewCallHandler(ICall call)
       {
        _call = call;
        _phoneCallAudioSender = new PhoneCallAudioSender();
        _phoneCallAudioSender.AttachToCall(call);
        _mediaConnector = new MediaConnector();
        _greetingMessageTimer = new Timer();
        _greetingMessageTimer.Elapsed += greetingMessageTimer_Elapsed;
        _greetingMessageTimer.Interval = 15000;
       }
```

here in this method of lowerMenu i am calling NewCallHandler function in the *var* variable

```
private void LowerMenu()
    {
        _call.CallStateChanged -= call_CallStateChanged;
        _call.DtmfReceived -= call_DtmfReceived;
        _greetingMessageTimer.Elapsed -= greetingMessageTimer_Elapsed;

        var  newCallHandler = NewCallHandler(_call);
        newCallHandler.BlindTransferNumber(_blindTransferNumber);
        newCallHandler.Completed += newCallHandler_Completed;
        newCallHandler.Start();
    }
}
```

i know this question has been asked before but can't find solution for my problem. Plz help me out in this matter. Thanks

Comment: Is `NewCallHandler` supposed to be a constructor?  Then is needs the same name as the class.  Is it a _method_? Then it needs a return type.

Comment: It is a method, but when i call this method inside var variable then it gives error of: var variable cannot be used with void

Comment: You need to give the method a return type.  Right now all it looks like you're doing is setting property values on a `CallHandler` instance - should it be _creating_ a `CallHandler` instance?

Comment: It _seems_ like you want a constructor (which is _also_ technically a method, just a special type).  Are you clear on the difference between the two?

Comment: yeah i am very much clear. NewCallHaandler is a method. Can u tell me any other way of how do  i call this method in new variable?

Comment: **Add a return type**.  Then return a value within the method.  That answer has been given in three answers and three comments now.  I'm not sure what part of that you don't understand.

Comment: More specifically - set the return type to the type of object that the method should return, right now you aren't returning anything...

Comment: There is no way this is not intended to be a constructor.

Comment: i added void in my method, then it gave me this error: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Comment: `void` means the method does not return anything.  You are trying to call a method that should return _something_.  The way you have written the "method" it looks A LOT like a constructor.  So either you don't really know what a constructor is or you need to create an instance in the method and return it.

Answer (score 3):

it *looks* like you are defining a constructor, by the way you are instantiating class level variables inside your method.  You even appear to do dependency injection, so I'm pretty sure this is intended to be a constructor.

A constructor name has to be the same name as the class.  you should rename your constructor to:

```
public CallHandler(ICall call)
```

Then, you would call it with:

```
var callHandler = new CallHandler(_call);
```

notice the `new` keyword.

Besides constructors, all methods must have a return type.  The compiler sees that your method isn't a constructor due to the name, assumes it's a normal method, and produces the error you see.

Comment: No, it doesn't, if you make the change I suggested.

Comment: CallHandler is a class and NewCallHandler is my method

Comment: It is a method, but when i call this method inside var variable then it gives error of: var variable cannot be used with void

Answer (score 0):

Methods have to have a return type declared or you have to use the keyword void if you don't want that method to return anything.

So change it to:

```
public void NewCallHandler(ICall call)
```

Comment: Yes i tried this, but when i call this method inside var variable then it gives error of: var variable cannot be used with void

Comment: Since you are using it for a variable you have to set it to whatever variable type you are wanting to return, and then at the end of that method you have to return said data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something from that method? If not you need to use void after public, otherwise you need put the type that you need to be returned.

Comment: From what I see in your code. You need to change the name from NewCallHandler to CallHandler.  In your method LowerMenu you need to do this.  var handler =  new CallHandler(_call);